# Find two text field that seem to have the same class using selenium ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am writing a simple script to find and enter text into First name and Last name fields for a web page profile in firefox. I have navigated to the page and inspected the element, however I have tried everything i can think of the find the element but nothing seems to work.  How can I find these fields using ruby, is there another way to inspect the field?

Both of these fields have field labels

First name inspect result

```
<div class="input__label">First Name</div>
<div class="input_row">
<div class="split_control">
<input class="input__input_wide" step="any" value="Bob">
```

Last name inspect result

```
<div class="input__label">Last Name</div>
<div class="input_row">
<div class="split_control">
<input class="input__input_wide" step="any" value="Smith">
```

Comment: Is this your own website you are testing?

Comment: You want to locate both the input fields?

Comment: Can you please give the full HTML source for this page so that we can find out the unique XPath for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following x-paths:

1. First Name element: `//div[text()='First Name']/following-sibling::div/div/input`
2. Last Name element: `//div[text()='Last Name']/following-sibling::div/div/input`

In code,

```
first_name = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[text()='First Name']/following-sibling::div/div/input")
first_name.send_keys "FName"

last_name = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[text()='Last Name']/following-sibling::div/div/input")
last_name.send_keys "LName"
```

Comment: thank you everyone for your suggestions.  The dev ended up adding an id for each field, however when i tried them I still get 'element not found'.  I wondered if it's because they have a space (id= First Name & id = Last Name).  I will need to go back to the Dev and ask him to change it.  Thanks again

Comment: Yes, Id value shouldn't have space in it. Also check whether the elements are inside a frame. if it is inside a frame, you will get not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

Write the xpath like given below

```
driver.find_element(xpath: "//div[normalize-space()='First Name']/following::input").send_keys "FirstName"
```

For LastName

```
driver.find_element(xpath: "//div[normalize-space()='Last Name']/following::input").send_keys "LastName"
```